# Issue in assigning the value for a key in dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionary like so...

```
[
  {
    "sellingPrice" : "200",
    "transaction_id" : "COD",
    "shipping_charges" : "",
    "id" : "3",
    "payment_method" : "",
    "taxes" : "0",
    "applied_coupon_code" : "",
    "discount_price" : "",
    "quantity" : "13",
    "transaction_type" : "COD",
    "remaining_balance" : "",
    "grand_total" : ""
  },
  {
    "sellingPrice" : "200",
    "transaction_id" : "COD",
    "shipping_charges" : "",
    "id" : "22",
    "payment_method" : "",
    "taxes" : "0",
    "applied_coupon_code" : "",
    "discount_price" : "",
    "quantity" : "3",
    "transaction_type" : "COD",
    "remaining_balance" : "",
    "grand_total" : ""
  }
]
```

I have something called "partial amount" with a value of 50. Now, I want to iterate over the array of dictionary, check if the `partial amount` is less than the `sellingPrice` and if it is less then subtract the `partial amount` from it and the resultant value will be assigned to the key `remaining_balance`

So in this case, 50 will be subtracted from the first `sellingPrice` of 200 to give the value of `remaining_balance` of the 1st dictionary as 150. Since there is now nothing left of that `partial amount` of 50 since it been fully used up, the 2nd `remaining_balance` will have the value of its `sellingPrice` of 200. So the 1st `remaining_balance` will be 150 & the 2nd `remaining_balance` will be 200.

This is what I tried so far..but it just doesn't seem to work...

```
for (index, dict) in self.appDelegate.arrayOfDictionary.enumerated() {
    for element in dict {                
        if element.key == "sellingPrice" {
            let PAinTxtField =  alertController.textFields?.first?.text)!
            var thePA = (Int(PAinTxtField ) ?? 0) //This is partial amount

            let theSP = (Int("\(element.value)") ?? 0) //This is selling price
            if thePA < theSP {
                self.remainingAmt = theSP - thePA
                var dictCopy = dict
                dictCopy["remaining_balance"] = "\(self.remainingAmt)" //The mistake seems to be because of this line. But cannot figure out what exactly...:(

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once again, why don't you use a custom struct as data model? And why do you use the type `String` rather than `Int` for the numeric values? And why do you enumerate the dictionary rather than getting the value for that particular key directly? Those three points make the code cumbersome and inefficient.

Comment: what you get error?

Comment: you are right @vadian. But the reason I used string is I have to pass the entire array of dictionary as a parameter in my API call. And the numbers are required to be in string there...Also not sure how can I get the value for that particular key directly...:(

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya The error is the key `remaining_balance ` is not getting the proper values of 150 & 200 respectively (as in my case.)

Comment: remove this line var dictCopy = dict and replace dictCopy with dict in this line dictCopy["remaining_balance"] = "\(self.remainingAmt)"

Comment: I would bet it is because you are assigning value to dictionary copy, thinking it will overwrite original value. Put a print under `dictCopy["remaining_balance"] = ...` and print out its value. Is it correct there?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
self.appDelegate.arrayOfDictionary[index] = dictCopy //replace new copyDict with old dict
```

Comment: ok @Salman Ghumsani. But will this be instead of this `dictCopy["remaining_balance"] = "\(self.remainingAmt)"`

Comment: No, write this line after `dictCopy["remaining_balance"] = "\(self.remainingAmt)"`

Comment: Simply one line will give you the desired result

Comment: .@Salman Ghumsani this does give the value of the first`remaining_balance ` as 150(200-50). But the second `remaining_balance` should be now 200 itself since there is nothing left of the partial amount of 50 to be subtracted from.

Comment: Try to figure out your logic.

Comment: Figured the issue by another method, @Salman Ghumsani. But this line `self.appDelegate.arrayOfDictionary[index] = dictCopy` was helpful. Thanks..Have given an upvote...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
var partialAmount = 50

arrayOfDictionary =  arrayOfDictionary.map { (dict) -> [String:Any] in
    var mutableDict : [String:Any] = dict
    if let sellingPrice = dict["sellingPrice"] as? String{
        if partialAmount < Int(sellingPrice)!{
            let remainingBalance = Int(sellingPrice)! - partialAmount
            partialAmount -= partialAmount
            mutableDict["remaining_balance"] = "\(remainingBalance)"
            return mutableDict
        }
        return dict
    }
    return dict
}
```

Comment: confused with line `if partialAmount - partialAmount >= 0 {
                partialAmount -= partialAmount
            }` @technerd. Will this not always be 0?

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the keys type for dictionary.

```
let array:[Dictionary<String,Any>] = [["sellingPrice" : "200"],
                 ["sellingPrice" : "200"]]
```